# Pressing w after cmd-` causes window close

Tags: keyboard, macos

**Summary**

I'm running into a curious behavior where pressing <kbd>w</kbd> after <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> (to switch windows of an application) causes the switched-to window to close, as if I had input <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd>, rather than just inputting <kbd>w</kbd>. This has arisen several times where I'm switching between Chrome windows and typing a message in one of them; when I switch back and start typing a word that begins with "w" that window closes.

Running Sierra (10.12.2). Reproduced on Mac Pro and on 13in Macbook Pro after restart.

I am running various background applications but wanted to see if anyone could reproduce this first.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Open any application that supports multiple tabs and multiple windows. I tested this with Google Chrome and with Sublime Text 3.
2. Open two windows, each with two tabs.
3. Try using the <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> shortcut to switch between windows.
4. After switching between windows with <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> and letting go of those keys, quickly press <kbd>w</kbd>.

**Expected:** <kbd>w</kbd> gets input into the window I just switched to.

**Actual:** The window closes, in the same way that it would if I had input <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd>.

Comment: Currently running 10.12.2 on a 2015 Macbook; could not reproduce the issue. Have you configured any custom shortcuts on your machines from either 'System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts' or a 3rd party application?

Comment: Running 10.12.2 on a 2013 MacBook Pro and cannot reproduce unless the ⌘ key is still pressed when the W key is pressed. (Which of course should close the window Tab then.)

Comment: Does it happen in safe mode or in a different user account?